# how can I parse string "2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT" to local date time?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

how can I parse `2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT` to local date time?

I have trimmed the quotation marks from start and end leaving me `2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT` but when I use `DateTime.Parse` it omits to parse the time?

```
DateTime.Parse("2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT")
{2/21/2015 12:00:00 PM}
    Date: {2/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 21
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 52
    Hour: 12
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 2
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 635601168000000000
    TimeOfDay: {12:00:00}
    Year: 2015
```

Comment: Any tried code would be helpful

Comment: I went to get the code I tried from VS but you must have down voted in record time. The question would not have been there for even 5 seconds!

Comment: That is because the hour is GMT, while you (your computer) are probably GMT+1, so your hour is right. Try changing the minutes from 00 to 01, and you'll see that the time is correctly parsed.

Comment: I think you should complete question and then submit it once you are sure everything is in place. You look experience with your reputation

Comment: @xanatos - yes that was it. Thank you. Put as an answer and I'll mark it for you

Comment: @kurasa agree with what you, users try to downvote too soon. And when they see a downvote they continue to downvote.. FYI it wasn't me :)

Comment: @KcDoD ahhh...sorry mate. Thought it was you. Never mind :)

Comment: Also, "it omits to parse the time" is a little bit to strong and vague, the result is not 1/1/1970 ! Maybe you should look at local/UTC problems and specify your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is GMT, while your computer is probably GMT+1, so what you are seeing is a `DateTime` in "local" time. To check for it, try changing the minutes to `01` for example. You'll see that the time is correctly parsed. or you could try to use the `ToUniversalTime()` method of `DateTime` and see that the time returned by this method is the same as in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide the format to avoid any risk of bad parsing.

About parse :

- GMT is parsed and the string is considered as universal time.
- The return kind is either `local` or `unspecified`. See the remarks in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

So when time zone is know, the result is always in local time, and the corresponding time shift is added.

```
var s1 = "2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT";
var s2 = "2015.02.21 1:00 AM";
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(s1);
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse(s2);

Console.WriteLine("dt1 is : " + dt1.Kind);  // local with time shift.
Console.WriteLine("dt2 is : " + dt2.Kind);  // unspecified without time shift.
```

You have to convert to universal time to find back the time you provided.

```
string s = "2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT";

// dt is the local time corresponding to the UTC time provided by "s"
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt 'GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);    // 21/02/2015 02:00:00 (I live in France GMT+1)

// Go back to universal time.
var udt = dt.ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(udt);    // 21/02/2015 01:00:00
```

Also you may want to parse a specified GMT like `2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT+1`.

The solution is :

```
string s = "2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT+1";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt 'GMT'z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);   // 21/02/2015 01:00:00 (I live in France GMT+1)
```

Comment: It is better to use `"yyyy.MM.dd h:mm tt 'GMT'"` where `'GMT'` is in single quotes. Otherwise the `M` in `GMT` could be taken to mean "month", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Kind for your DateTime. By default when you're converting a string to DateTime, the system treats it as Local. Try the following:

```
DateTime dtLocal = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2015.02.21 1:00 AM"), DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: In this case, the GMT is recognized and the result is already in UTC.

Comment: @Orace It converts the string, "2015.02.21 1:00 AM" to DateTime marking it as UTC. Next, the .ToLocalTime() convert this time to the local machine's DateTime. So what's your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I speak about @kurasa case. There is `GMT` in the string to parse, so the result already has a kind. `DateTime.Parse("2015.02.21 1:00 AM GMT").kind` is local (with time shift). So you do not have to use `SpecifyKind`.